# Why do bools take less memory in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, memory, memory-management, boolean

On the [*Oracle website*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3.4), it says that bools take 32 bits on the stack, but 8 in an array. I'm having trouble understanding why it is that they would take less in a group than in as singles. How are they stored, and what difference does it make? If arrays of bools are more efficient, why has that technology not been transferred over to singles?

Also, why not 1 bit?

And what is the difference between how a 64 but system and a 32 bit system stores these?

Thanks!

Comment: Not relevant to the issue but please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27162/ethics-of-editing-out-gratitude

Comment: Thanks for the link, @alfasin, and thanks for following the rule... I put my gratitude back on because I really am thankful for this awesome site, and I feel like a 'Thanks!' really isn't going to hinder any comprehension. It kinda says "I'm a real person and I'm grateful that you are paying my post some attention!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look, when it comes to stack, one must keep in mind that speed is the most important thing. For example, consider the following:

```
 void method(int foo, boolean bar, String name) ....
```

Then the stack just after entering the method looks like this:

```
 |-other variables-|-...-|-name-|-bar-|-foo-|---- return address etc. --
 ^
 stack pointer
```

These are all quantities on a word boundary, symbolized by `|`. Sure, the JVM could (theoretically, but see below) store the boolean in a single byte. But one must keep in mind that 32bit loads may be slower when they don't address word boundaries. Depending on architecture, it may be impossible to go through a pointer that does not live on a word boundary. Or it may be impossible use the quantity in a floating point instruction, etc. etc.

In addition, the byte code format can only address the *n*-th word on the stack. If this were not so, addresses relative to the stack pointer would have to be specified in bytes and this would mean that almost any stack access would have two bits that are irrelevant most of the time, as the majority of arguments will be words (int, float or reference) or double words (long, double).

What is never possible is to use 1 single bit for booleans. Why? Because bits are not directly addressable. The smallest addressable unit is the byte.

You can still store 32 booleans in an **int** if you feel that you should save on memory.

Answer (score 7):

A boolean value can be stored as a single binary digit, but our computers group values as a convenience. The smallest unit practically dealt with is a byte, the next largest being a word. A byte is, in modern hardware, always 8 bits. 32 bits has emerged as the standard for a word. Even our 64 bit computers can deal in 32 bit words effectively. It is much more convenient to store a bool in whatever unit comes naturally than as a single bit. In an array, the natural unit would be a byte, since you can address any byte in memory. On the stack, which is a word stack, the natural unit is a word. You could stuff bools into bytes and words and work on pulling them out again bit by bit, literally, but that's less efficient than storing them in bytes or words because modern memories are large, so CPU speed is more of a concern. You wouldn't want to waste all of the time it takes to pack bits in compactly, so we waste memory instead, since it is more expendable.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. One more thing though... Does a 64 bit machine store it any differently?

Comment: Our 64 bit x64 architectures are based on the older 32 bit x86 architectures and will often deal in 32 bits when 64 bits is not needed. Give me a moment to look at x64 to determine whether the call stack is always 64 bits and I will get right back to you on this.

Comment: In x64 architecture, the stack will always be 64 bits. When a 64 bit CPU runs a 32 bit program, it is storing all 32 bit values in 64 bit fields on the stack, so half of the storage space is wasted. A bool will be stored on the stack of an x64 computer as a 64 bit word.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the way CPUs work, all operations are done in 32 bits. If you have a single bool, the only realistic thing a compiler can do is zero out the rest of the 24 bits and save that to the stack, since it's not practical to scan your java file for other bools to and store them all in the same 32 bit memory block.

If you have an array of bools, it's simple to just reference them in blocks of 4, so it's only 8 bits per bool.

Note that this only applies to 32 bit applications/machines.

Comment: My follow up question would be, why not use 1 bit per bool and store them in blocks of 32? That would be even more efficient, wouldn't it?

Comment: Well, the answer to this is that the jvm just isn't built to support 1 bit operations, so a "bool" is just a byte that goes by another name. The amount of memory you'd save by using 1 bit is so small it's just not worth the added computational complexity.

Comment: There's probably more overhead involved if they stored the bools into a single bit as todays CPU's aren't designed to go grab a single bit of memory.

Comment: This is answere is not quite right. Im not aware how things work inside the JVM but atleast on x86 memory addresse reference single bytes, please clarify this.

Comment: @Josh this method is used and called a bitset, its often used in low-level architectures to pass flags and where size is important, e.g networking.

Comment: See my answer. It might explain some things.

Comment: @Paranaix I didn't say it wasn't possible, read big endians response, that's basically what I wanted to say but much better.

Comment: @Paranix Yeah you're right, that was a slip up. That bit of info wasn't necessary for the reasoning anyways, so I took it out.